# Is there a "Block HTML tags" filter?

Tags: 9

I am wondering if there is a contrib module which does the reverse of the core "Limit allowed HTML tags" (poorly named oxymoron, this should just be "Allow HTML tags") by allowing me to simply list the tags which I do not want allowed?

Basically I am trying to only block H1s (obviously editors should never be adding H1s to Body fields) and also EM tags. At the moment I need to enable the "limit allow" filter and add a full list of tags except the 2 I want to block. And every couple weeks the editors come up with another tag or attr which needs to be allowed. This would be much simpler to just have a "Block HTML tags" filter. Ideally this would just be a change to the core filter to have a block/allow option with this filter.

I suspect writing this isn't too difficult (just copy the core "allow" one and modify) but thought I would check if anyone knows of an existing contrib module which already exists.

Comment: If the two tags are not listed in limit allowed tags, how are they still rendering?

Comment: (poorly named oxymoron, this should just be "Allow HTML tags") <- Honestly, no. The former is grammatically correct, the latter is not. Maybe "Allowed HTML tags".  But that's neither here nor there

Comment: Sure, "Allowed", my point was "limit" makes no sense there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a general purpose "block HTML tags" module, but the [Markdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown) module has a **Disallowed Raw HTML** setting for escaping certain tags.  However, this uses the [League\Commonmark library](https://commonmark.thephpleague.com/2.3/extensions/disallowed-raw-html/) and so is limited to Commonmark Markdown.